# For Foundation/ZURB, what is the random "data-section-content" for?

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio-2012

```html
<div class="section-container accordion" data-section="accordion">
  <section class="active">
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

In that code block, on line 4 there's a random data-section-content (from [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html#variations)) and my IDE seems to hate it. What's it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute "data-section-content" stands the content which is going to be hidden/visible depending on the active tab.
Most probably, your IDE is not supporting HTML5 attributes and you should define it like xhtml: data-section-content="data-section-content"